# Can't install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Tags: nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64

GeForce GT 730

Cuda 10.1
Can I install tensorflow gpu with my system ?

After running `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` get this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-profiler (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nvidia-visual-profiler (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nsight-compute (= 10.1.243-3)
                       Recommends: nsight-systems (= 10.1.243-3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It happened after I incorrectly install the wrong nvidia driver 495 instead of 390 when I was trying to install tensorlfow (still couldn't unstall it)

I went over lots of posts and answer/questions but none really helped
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuda 10 will not work with 390, minimum driver version is 410 and 410 does not support GT 730...nice tricky situation.....:)